# R claims that data is non-numeric, but after writing to file is numeric

Tags: r

I have read in a table in R, and am trying to take log of the data. This gives me an error that the last column contains non-numeric values:

```
> log(TD_complete)
Error in Math.data.frame(list(X2011.01 = c(187072L, 140815L, 785077L,  : 
non-numeric variable in data frame: X2013.05
```

The data "looks" numeric, i.e. when I read it my brain interprets it as numbers. I can't be totally wrong since the following will work:

```
> write.table(TD_complete,"C:\\tmp\\rubbish.csv", sep = ",")
> newdata = read.csv("C:\\tmp\\rubbish.csv")
> log(newdata)
```

The last line will happily output numbers.

This doesn't make any sense to me - either the data is numeric when I read it in the first time round, or it is not. Any ideas what might be going on?

EDIT: Unfortunately I can't share the data, it's confidential.

Comment: The fact that it gives number doesn't mean that it is (always!) numeric in R

Comment: Take a look at `str(TD_complete)` and then explore coercing columns directly to numeric:  `as.numeric(TD_complete[,1])`.  Often this will give a warning about `NAs produced`... Then find those rows:  `TD_complete[is.na(as.numeric(TD_complete[,1])),]`.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I tried `as.numeric(TF_complete)` and that gives an error `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`, although the documentation doesn't suggest any limitations on the input to as.numeric ("as.numeric(x, ...) - x object to be coerced or tested."). Any idea why it would work on a colummn but not on the whole matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the colClasses argument of read.csv(), where you can specify what type each column should be read and stored as. That might not be so helpful if you have a large number of columns, but using it makes sure R doesn't have to guess what type of data you're using.

Just because "the last line will happily output numbers" doesn't mean R is treating the values as numeric.

Also, it would help to see some of your data.

Comment: Thanks, using colClasses fixed it.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - could you give an example where a function taking numeric values as input would return numbers even if the input was non-numeric?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the actual data or a sample of it, help will be much easier.

In this case I assume R has the column in question saved as a string and writes it without any parantheses into the CSV file. Once there, it reads it again and does not bother to interpret a value without any characters as anything else than a number. In other words, by writing and reading a CSV file you converted a string containing only numbers into a proper integer (or float).

But without the actual data or the rest of the code this is mere conjecture.

Comment: You are stating the obvious without giving any reasons. The question is: What would cause R to interpret a numerical columns as strings? Regarding your answer - why would it ever write parentheses into a CSV file? Do you mean quotes?